# Using partial textInput in Shiny as variable in R

Tags: r, shiny, textinput

I would like to take a part of textInput in Shiny to create a variable that will in turn be matched to values in a dataframe (DF) and create textOutput based on that matched value. Say I have an textInput with typical inputs being e.g. ABC 123, ABC 234, ABC 345, BCD 123, BCD 234, BCD 345. I also have a DF that contains one column (Col1) with the 'first' part of a typical textInput i.e. ABC, BCD and another column with a set of corresponding values (Col2) like so

```
DF <-
   Col1 Col2
1  ABC    W
2  BCD    Y
3  CDE    X
4  DEF    Z
```

I would like to take textInput, say "ABC 123", select only the 'first' part of it ("ABC") then use this string to find its corresponding value in DF$Col2 and create textOutput in Shiny to populate/output that value, in this case value "W". Similarly, if the user input in textInput (input$UserInput) is CDE 345, I would like the output value to be displayed to be "X".

I can create the 'first' section text and output into relevant space but have trouble with the additional part of using it to find corresponding value in the DF and outputting that instead.

I'm using this to isolate the 'first' part of the text input,

```
  output$first <- renderText({paste(substr(input$UserInput, 1, 
  nchar(input$UserInput)-4))})
```

This outputs the "ABC", "CDE" etc string but I have problems using this for the second step of finding the correct value in DF$Col2 and outputting that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap your `substr` call into a reactive function.

```
mySelection <- reactive({
    inputString <- paste(substr(input$UserInput, 1, nchar(input$UserInput)-4))
    return(inputString)
})
```

now the value of `inputString` will change based on the value of `input$UserInput`, and can be called anywhere in your script (as `mySelection()`  ).

```
output$first <- renderText({mySelection()})
```

you can then extract the value you want with `DF[which(DF$col1 == mySelection()),]$col2`

Comment: Great, and what is the best way to use the inputString to get the relevant value from the DF so that the final output in mySelection is the value 10 say if the user input is ABC 123.

Comment: `DF[which(DF$col1 == mySelection()),]$col2`

Comment: I am unable to get the correct value into output$first, I am getting the first part of the input$UserInput (i.e. ABC), but I would like to use that string to match the corresponding value in DF column 2, so that output$first actually outputs the value 10 instead. I seem to be missing something or a step. Any help much appreciated.

Comment: It would be much easier to help you.if you edit your original question with an example of the DF you are using.

Comment: Thank you, I have changed the original explanation and added the relevant information.

Comment: This seems to work adding paste() into the code so that `output$first <- renderText({paste(DF[which(DF$col1 == mySelection()),]$col2)})` , thank you!

Comment: `paste()` converts its arguments to character strings, meaning that your table contained factors or other non character values. If you convert everything to character, you should be able to avoid pasting.  Mark the thread as solved if you are happy with the answers :D